# Publishing rate of gazebo sensor plugins broken on ROS fuerte?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

it appears to me that there is a performance regression in the plugin
update (publishing) rate in ROS fuerte compared to gazebo in ROS
electric. I already posted a detailed description on
answers.ros.org: http://answers.ros.org/question/43960/publishing-rate-of-gazebo-sensor-plugins-broken-on-fuerte/
but failed to get an answer so far.

Basically, on electric data is output to ROS topics as expected, while
the data is published with high jitter and much lower than desired
rate in fuerte. I'm not sure this has been the case from the start, if
this a recent performance regression, or if I'm doing something wrong.
Whatever it is, the current state is unusable for sensor simulation.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

System is Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64, electric and fuerte from .debs (up to
date), Nvidia proprietary drivers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6/publishing-rate-of-gazebo-sensor-plugins-broken-on-ros-fuerte?/) by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

sorry, this must have fallen off the treadmill at some point. I took a brief look, and SensorManager::Update() inlines image rendering update with the laser sensor update. I think splitting up the two updates into separate thereads should solve this issue.

See [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/20/laser-scan-ray-sensor-updates-erratic-and).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0